# addGestureRecognizer not firing if statement in swift4

Tags: ios, if-statement, constraints, swift4, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to use a if statement when the uses touches the imageview it changes the constraints. Right now my code changes from small to big but it does not change from big to small. So the if statement only works one time but does not work again.

```
 var counter = 0

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleRegisterC))
        FIRE.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        FIRE.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        print(counter)

    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.addSubview(FIRE)
    FIRE.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true



    FIRE.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
    FIRE.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700).isActive = true
     FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



    @objc func handleRegisterC(sender: UIButton){

        counter += 1


        if counter % 2 == 0 {


            FIRE.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


            FIRE.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
            FIRE.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700).isActive = true
            FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        }
        if counter % 2 == 1 {
            FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            FIRE.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            FIRE.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            FIRE.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        }


    }



}
```

Comment: I don't think the `if statement` is working only once (you can put a print statement in each block to confirm). I think the problem is that you have two sets of constraints that are active at the same time. What you probably want to do is to alternate between these two sets; setting one of them to be active while the other one to be inactive

Comment: I dont know how to do that could you show me?

Comment: I've added an answer. Try adding that in your view controller

Comment: Did the solution help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `if statement` is working only once (you can put a print statement in each block to confirm). I think the problem is that you have two sets of constraints that are active at the same time. What you probably want to do is to alternate between these two sets; setting one of them to be active while the other one to be inactive. Try something like this

```
enum Size {
    case big
    case small
}
var counter = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(FIRE)
    changeSizeTo(.small)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleRegisterC))
    FIRE.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    FIRE.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

private func changeSizeTo(_ size: Size) {
    FIRE.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = size == .small
    FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = size == .small
    FIRE.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = size == .small
    FIRE.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700).isActive = size == .small
    FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = size == .big
    FIRE.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = size == .big
    FIRE.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = size == .big
    FIRE.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = size == .big
    FIRE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

@objc func handleRegisterC(sender: UIButton){
    counter += 1
    changeSizeTo(counter % 2 == 0 ? .small : .big)
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is have the same effect. It works once then it does not work again in the xcode log there is a lot of complaints of constraints.

Comment: Can you upload your project somewhere and share the link?